# Does AMI have all the environment of its source EC2 instance? How to save all tools and configs with AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have created an EC2 instance in AWS. I have set up Node.js environment on it, installed all necessary tools (Ruby, Nginx, MongoDB, MySQL, etc), configured `.bashrc`, aliases, `apt`, etc.

Now I would like to save this pre-configured instance as a sample to create the same full-featured instances from it in future.

My question is: Creating an AMI, does AWS save all my configs and installed tools in that AMI? So that when I re-create a new instance from it, my new instance will have everything installed and pre-configured? Or how to save all tools and configs with AMI?

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things, an AMI is a bootable snapshot of the root volume filesystem of the EC2 instance you created it from.
So yes, everything that you installed on the disk, including ruby nginx bashrc etc, should be in there when you create an instance out of it.

Creating an AMI is easy (Full docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)):

1. Launch an EBS-backed EC2 instance
2. SSH into the instance
3. Do your things
4. Right click on the instance -> image -> create image
5. You will have an AMI a few minutes after

Note: You can also [create an AMI out of instance-store EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html)